# Checking for balanced parentheses in C

Tags: c

so the program should open a .c file and check for balanced parentheses, however my program keeps crashing. I think the problem maybe in the `while` loop to check for every character in the file.

```
typedef struct nodo {
    char llave;        
    struct nodo *sig;  
} nodo;

void push(struct nodo **top, int nuevo_dato);
int pop(struct nodo **top);

bool match(char signo1, char signo2);
bool check(FILE *fp);

int main() {    
    int k;

    printf("Seleccionar Opción\n1.Analizar 1\n2.Analizar 2\n3.Analizar 3\n4.Analizar 4\n5.Salir");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    do {
        switch (k) {
        case 1: ;
            FILE *f1;                    
            f1 = fopen("1.c", "r");
            if (check(f1))
                printf("Damn");
            fclose(f1);
            break;
        case 2: ;
            FILE *f2;
            f2 = fopen("2.c", "r");
        case 3: ;
            FILE *f3;
            f3 = fopen("3.c", "r");
        case 4: ;
            FILE *f4;
            f4 = fopen("4.c", "r");            
        }    
    } while (k!=5);
}

bool check(FILE *fp) {
    int j, i = 0;
    char *signo;
    nodo *stack = NULL;
    signo = malloc(100000);
    while (signo = fgetc(fp) != EOF {

        if (signo[i] == '{' || signo[i] == '(' || signo[i] == '[') 
            push(&stack, signo[i]);

        if (signo[i] == '}' || signo[i] == ')' || signo[i] == ']') {
            if (stack == NULL) {
                return false; 
            }
            else if (!match(pop(&stack), signo[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}

bool match(char signo1, char signo2) {
    if (signo1 == '(' && signo2 == ')')
        return true;
    else if (signo1 == '{' && signo2 == '}')
        return true;
    else if (signo1 == '[' && signo2 == ']')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void push(struct nodo **top, int nueva_llave) {
    nodo *nuevo_nodo = (struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));

    if (nuevo_nodo == NULL) {
        printf("Stack overflow \n");
    }           

    /* put in the data  */
    nuevo_nodo->llave  = nueva_llave;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    nuevo_nodo->sig = (*top);  

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*top) = nuevo_nodo;
}

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct nodo **top_ref) {
    char res;
    struct nodo *top;

    /*If stack is empty then error */
    if (*top_ref == NULL) {
        printf("Stack overflow \n");
    } else {
        top = *top_ref;
        res = top->llave;
        *top_ref = top->sig;
        free(top);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can't seem to find where the problem is". Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately which line of code is triggering the crash and then you can debug further from there.

Comment: `scanf("%d",k);` --> `scanf("%d",&k);`

Comment: `while(signo=fgetc(fp) !=EOF) {` is wrong.

Comment: You don't have `break;` statements in your `switch`.  You don't call `check` except on `f1`.  You don't call `fclose()`.  You don't check that `fopen()` succeeded.  The switch is clumsy; have the user type the name of the file, not a number.  You don't check that `scanf()` succeeded.  The loop `for (j=1;j=='\n';j++){` is most peculiar — basically wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 

I added a break; statement and deleted the for loop.

I'm only checking f1, but it still crashes

Comment: If I copy the code from the updated question, it doesn't compile for me because there are lots of warnings.  For example, it complains about: `while(signo=fgetc(fp) !=EOF) {` which has multiple issues.  `signo` is a `char *`; it points to allocated memory.  Your assignment assigns an integer to the pointer, leaking the memory.  Since `fgetc()` only returns one character, it isn't clear what you're planning here.  Probably, `char signo;` makes some sense, delete the `malloc()` (and the `free()` if there is one), and use `while ((signo = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {` or thereabouts.  I doubt that's all.

Comment: This assignment is very difficult. To correctly balance parentheses a C source code, you must parse comments, strings and character constants with all special cases, including escaped linefeeds, not to mention digraphs and trigraphs...

Answer (score 0):

Specific problems with your code: your `push`, `pop` and `struct nodo` aren't consistent about what type of data they are encapsulating, sometimes an `int` sometimes a `char`; your `check()` function can't decide if `signo` is a character or a string, and though it returns `false`, it never returns `true`, which it should; your error handling is insufficient if not incorrect.

Below is a rework of your code that basically runs.  It's not finished code, it needs more error checking and other finishing touches (I stripped out files 2 - 4 as they weren't important to the debugging, you'll need to add them back):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct nodo {
    char llave;
    struct nodo *sig;
} nodo;

void push(struct nodo **top, int nuevo_dato);
int pop(struct nodo **top);
bool match(int signo1, int signo2);
bool balanced(FILE *fp);

int main() {
    int k;
    printf("Seleccionar Opción\n1.Analizar 1\n5.Salir\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    FILE *f1;

    switch (k) {
        case 1:
            f1 = fopen("1.c", "r");

            if (balanced(f1)) {
                printf("Balanced!\n");
            } else {
                printf("Unbalanced!\n");
            }

            fclose(f1);

            break;

        case 5:
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool balanced(FILE *fp) {
    nodo *stack = NULL;

    int signo;

    while ((signo = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

        if (signo == '{' || signo == '(' || signo == '[') {
            push(&stack, signo);
        } else if (signo == '}' || signo == ')' || signo == ']') {

            if (stack == NULL) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!match(pop(&stack), signo) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool match(int signo1, int signo2) {
    if (signo1 == '(' && signo2 == ')')
        return true;
    else if (signo1 == '{' && signo2 == '}')
        return true;
    else if (signo1 == '[' && signo2 == ']')
        return true;

    return false;
}

void push(struct nodo **top, int nueva_llave) {

    nodo *nuevo_nodo = malloc(sizeof(nodo));

    if (nuevo_nodo == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* put in the data */
    nuevo_nodo->llave = nueva_llave;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    nuevo_nodo->sig = *top;

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    *top = nuevo_nodo;
}

/* Function to pop an item from stack */
int pop(struct nodo **top_ref) {

    if (*top_ref == NULL) {
        /* If stack is empty then error */
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack underflow\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct nodo *top = *top_ref;
    int res = top->llave;
    *top_ref = top->sig;
    free(top);

    return res;
}
```

Note that the above code would not pass it's own balanced test as lines like these:

```
if (signo == '{' || signo == '(' || signo == '[') {
```

would trip the balance logic and return `false`.  A simple, generic C program should pass, however.

My overall recommendation is test more as you code -- don't expect to debug a finished program.